# add sum() or count () to query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a `SELECT` which has result:

```
  | NAZEV
1   test
2   test
3   test111
4   test111
5   test111
6   test12
```

I want to add function `SUM()` [or `count`] to result was:

```
  | NAZEV      | Pocet
1   test          2
2   test111       3
3   test12        1
```

My current script:

```
select   sb.nazev from Aplikacni_log lg 
join zadavaci_postup zp on zp.id = lg.id_zp
join subjekt sb on sb.id = zp.id_zadavatel
where lg.create_cas > to_date('08.11.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
order by sb.nazev asc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use functions like SUM() and COUNT() for a specific field you need to use a GROUP BY on that field.
Some samples could be found at `http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp`
your code should become:

```
select   sb.nazev, count(sb.nazev) from Aplikacni_log lg 
join zadavaci_postup zp on zp.id = lg.id_zp
join subjekt sb on sb.id = zp.id_zadavatel
where lg.create_cas > to_date('08.11.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
group by sb.nazev
order by sb.nazev asc
```

Comment: "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: try now, a column was missing. I added the count(xxx) and the group by xxx

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `sum` or `count` *and a column to group on*, you need the `group by` clause:

```
select   sb.nazev, count(*)
from Aplikacni_log lg 
...
group by sb.nazev
order by sb.nazev asc
```

If you don't need a column (or columns) to group on, you can omit the `group by`. The results will be the total `count` or `sum`:

```
select   count(*)
from Aplikacni_log lg 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL `Sum()` and `Count()` is different thing, `Sum()` used to sum the value from the resultant row and `Count()` used to `Count()` the no of row.

let:
Result:

```
name |value
A    |10
A    |3
A    |4
```

then the `sum()` will return `A and (10+3+4)=17`, but
`Count()` will return `A and (1+1+1)=3` in a single row but you have to use [GROUP BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) clause.

For Your Script:

try

```
select   sb.nazev as NAZEV,count(sb.nazev) as Pocet from Aplikacni_log lg 
join zadavaci_postup zp on zp.id = lg.id_zp
join subjekt sb on sb.id = zp.id_zadavatel
where lg.create_cas > to_date('08.11.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
group by sb.nazev
order by sb.nazev asc
```